# Short story about crime-free future and a suicide device

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to find a short story about a crime-free future.

Also story has mention of a suicide device fixed on the back which leads to decrease in violent and aggressive behavior in future.

Comment: Have a look at [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and add as many of the details listed there as you can in your question. That can only help your search.

Answer (score 5):

The story is "Common Denominator" by John D. MacDonald.  (Yes, *that* John D. MacDonald and appears in his short story collection "Other Times, Other Worlds".

"In a moment of depression, I take these two smallest fingers of each hand.  I reach behind me and I press the two fingers, held firmly together to a space in the middle of my back.  A tiny capsule at the base of my brain is activated and I am dead within the thousandth part of a second."

https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56205

Covers: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?56205

Comment: What is so significant about John D. Macdonald?

Comment: MacDonald is far more widely known for his authorship of the "Travis McGee" detective novel series than he is for a couple of SF titles and a handful of short stories.  My wife has read virtually of of "McGee" and had no idea that MacDonald had written any SF at all.